# Scala order implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have some problem in scala order implicit, can someone help me?

Below are some classes definition, and what I want to do is to compare Leaf and Node through it's 'popularity'.

```
class Tree

case class EmptyTree() extends Tree

case class Leaf(label: String, popularity: Double) extends Tree

case class Node(popularity: Double, left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
```

for exampel:

```
val a = Leaf("a",10)
val b = Leaf("b",20)
val c = Node(30,a,b)
```

if we want to compare a and b through it's popularity, it is easy to do by adding the implicit transformations, like that:

```
implicit val leavesOrder = new Ordering[Leaf] {
override def compare(x: Leaf, y: Leaf) = 
  implicitly[Ordering[Double]].compare(x.popularity, y.popularity)
}
```

but if I want to compare a and c through it's popularity, I am confused about it and don't konw how to add the implicit transformations?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Your title talks about implicit order but you seem to be looking for implicit conversions?

Comment: You could create a `new Ordering[Tree]`

Comment: Sorry about that, I will modify the tile.@YuvalItzchakov

Comment: Could you describe in detail?@LukaJacobowitz

Comment: Sure, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id do something like this. Change your `Tree` class to a `sealed trait` this means the pattern matching is exhaustive so the compiler can tell you if your missing something. Then you need to match on each of the types that a Tree can be. Not all of them have a popularity.

```
sealed trait Tree

case object EmptyTree extends Tree

case class Leaf(label: String, popularity: Double) extends Tree

case class Node(popularity: Double, left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree

implicit val treeOrdering = new Ordering[Tree] {

  private val doubleOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[Double]]

  def compare(a: Tree, b: Tree): Int = {
    (a, b) match {
      case (Node(p1, _, _), Node(p2, _, _)) => doubleOrdering.compare(p1, p2)
      case (Leaf(_, p1), Node(p2, _, _)) => doubleOrdering.compare(p1, p2)
      case (Node(p1, _, _), Leaf(_, p2)) => doubleOrdering.compare(p1, p2)
      case (Leaf(_, p1), Leaf(_, p2)) => doubleOrdering.compare(p1, p2)
      case (EmptyTree, _) => -1
      case (_, EmptyTree) => 1
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying your method.

Comment: Hello,thanks in advance, when I try to test your code in my example, there come up with the following messages, "No implicit ordering defined for Leaf".   Below is my example:                                                                                                val a = Leaf("a", 3)
    val b = Leaf("b", 5)
    val e = Leaf("e", 6)
    val c = Node( 10, a, b)
    val d = Node( 11, c, a)

    val s = Array(e,a, b).sorted

Comment: change `val treeOrdering = ...` to `implicit val treeOrdering = ...`

Comment: You need Array[Tree](e,a, b).sorted https://gist.github.com/stephennancekivell/4f575c0462900509be824b8c7b877c09

Comment: That works, But why val s:Array[Tree] = Array(e, a, b).sorted not work?

Comment: The problem is that the ordering is defined for the trait, and the compiler is inferring the type of the child. I dont think there is a way for it to work magically. Type inference isnt perfect.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your Scala journey. Can you accept my answer and vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an implicit `Ordering` for `Tree` if you want to compare `Leaf`s and `Node`s.

Here's some (incomplete) code, on how you could do that:

```
implicit val treeOrder = new Ordering[Tree] {
  override def compare(x: Tree, y: Tree) = (x,y) match {
    case (Leaf(_,xP), Leaf(_,yP)) => xP compare yP
    case (Node(xP,_,_), Leaf(_,yP)) => xP compare yP
    case (Node(xP,_,_), Node(yP,_,_)) => xP compare yP
    case (EmptyTree(), _) => -1
    /* Add the rest of the cases here */
  }
}
```

Bonus points for changing `Tree` to be a `sealed trait`, so that the compiler can tell you when your pattern matching is incomplete :)

Comment: Hi Luka,thanks in advance, when I try to test your code in my example, there come up with the following messages, "No implicit ordering defined for Leaf". Below is my example: val a = Leaf("a", 3) val b = Leaf("b", 5) val e = Leaf("e", 6) val c = Node( 10, a, b) val d = Node( 11, c, a) val s = Array(e,a, b).sorted

Comment: Hmm, that works for me, can you show me more of your code?

Comment: It works, Should add the type Tree when initial the Array.

Comment: Yes, the type needs to be inferred as Tree, you can force that by using a type anotation, or the compiler will infer it for you when you have an Array of different types of the hierarchy. :)